# Is a gabion a good raised planter for a vegetable garden?

Tags: vegetables, container-gardening

I am looking for a raised planter for a vegetable garden -- likely approximately 2'H x 2'W x 8'L. I like the look of a gabion, but I was wondering about its suitability for a vegetable garden compared to the typical cedar, corrugated metal, or plastic/synthetic wood boxes. It will be placed on the sunny south side of my home in central Texas (i.e. hot during the summer!).

In particular, I was wondering how a gabion is for vegetables with respect to heat and evaporation:

1. Will it get too hot and retain too much heat at night?
2. Will evaporation be a problem between the heat and porous walls of rocks?

If you have any experience with a gabion for a vegetable garden, I'd like to hear your thoughts.

[image]